# Switch statement in base class needing to use a derived class's values

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, switch-statement, game-physics

I'm currently making my own game engine in C++ with SFML, and making a 2D platformer game.

My game's objects currently split into two categories:

1. Tiles: Bound to a grid, for easier collision checking
2. Entities: Can move freely, don't need to be in a grid

All the Entities are in a vector of pointers to the base class Entity, and of course contain some of its derived classes, such as "CharacterEntity". When cycling through the vector, the game engine calls the Entity's main function, which then calls the Entity or derived Entity's private functions, such as TileCollision().

The problem I am having is inside the Entity base class's collision function. The function takes a pointer to a Tile, determines what kind of Tile it is (each Tile has an enum class called TileType), and does different collisions depending on what kind of Tile it is.

```
void Entity::TileCollision(const Tile *pTile)

{
    /// If the Tile is null
    if (pTile == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (pTile->GetApplyCollision() == true)
    {
        sf::Vector2f tilePosition = pTile->GetPosition();
        sf::Vector2f tileDimensions = pTile->GetDimensions();
        switch (pTile->GetTileType())
        {
        case TileType::LADDERTOP:
            /// If Entity is going downwards
            if (m_speed.y >= 0) /// NEED TO ADD A CONDITION HERE
            {
                /// Check for X-Axis overlap
                if (m_position.x + m_dimensions.x / 2 > tilePosition.x &&
                    m_position.x - m_dimensions.x / 2 < tilePosition.x + tileDimensions.x)
                {
                    /// If in the current tick, the Entity's bottom side is above the LadderTop, though not two Tiles above, but it will be in the next tick
                    if (m_position.y + m_dimensions.y / 2 <= tilePosition.y &&
                        m_position.y + m_dimensions.y / 2 >= tilePosition.y - m_rMap.GetTileSize() &&
                        m_position.y + m_dimensions.y / 2 + m_speed.y > tilePosition.y)
                    {
                        m_position.y = tilePosition.y - m_dimensions.y / 2;
                        m_isOnGround = true;
                        m_speed.y = 0;
                        m_moveSpeed.y = 0;
                        m_vehiculeSpeed.y = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            /// More collision code for other Tiles... (not relevant here)
```

The problem I am having is that I want the Entity (or in this case, a derived Entity class such as CharacterEntity) to be able to go down, through the LadderTop Tile when it is pressing down.

The derived CharacterEntity class has variables like these to handle movement.

```
class CharacterEntity : public Entity
{
protected:
    bool m_isPressingUp;
    bool m_isPressingDown;
    bool m_isPressingLeft;
    bool m_isPressingRight;
    bool m_isPressingShift;
```

These booleans aren't just limited to determining if the key is pressed, but rather if the CharacterEntity WANTS to go in that direction. For instance, an AI creature would set m_isPressingLeft to true when it wants to go left, but that doesn't necessarily mean it can, it just means it will be triggering the functions that make it move left in its main function.

Now here's the problem: in the Entity base class's TileCollision function, I would ideally need to have access to the booleans, and use this if() clause to determine whether or not to apply the LadderTop collision:

```
if (m_speed.y >= 0 && m_isPressingDown == false)
```

However, because the TileCollision is inside the Entity class and the Entity class doesn't have those variables (because the Entity class was designed for Entities that cannot move on their own, but can be moved by external sources, such as arrows or pebbles), this cannot work.

What can I do to fix this? I have a feeling that this problem is due to a bigger problem with my handling of inheritance with switch statements.

I could make a derived TileCollision() class in CharacterEntity, but wouldn't that mean having to copy-paste all the current code, just for a different if() statement? Is there maybe a way to have something that would work like derived cases? I really don't know, and would like some advice.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why is the ability to "want" to go in a direction only a part of a derived class? Can't non-"Character" entities "want" things too?

Comment: CharacterEntities are the ones that have a will to do things, Entities are simply objects that can be moved around, like arrows or rocks. But either way, isn't this part of a bigger problem, something I'm not understanding about how I should be using OOP, inheritance or switch statements? Moving platforms, for instance, would also be a different derived class, as they have to be responsible for their own desire to move, and not just be moved by surrounding game objects like Entities are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost never switch on the type of an object. Add a virtual function (say to handle collisions) and implement it in the derived classes. That way your logic can be written directly in `CharacterEntity` where it already has access to all the necessary data.

Comment: Alright, but what if I want regular Entities, CharacterEntities, moving platforms, players, mobs, and a big number of other derived entities to all have very similar collisions with tiles, but only with small differences such as  this one? Wouldn't that mean having to have very large amounts of duplicate code for each overridden function?

Comment: No. Define the function at the right level of abstraction. If there is very similar logic with small differences then write it once, and express the differences via other virtual functions or member variables.

Comment: Ahhh this sounds good. So do you think a derived TileCollision function in each of the derived classes would work, and I could make private functions such as LadderTopCollision that would change, and each case would call a function like LadderTopCollision? Or do you instead suggest having one virtual function for every type of collision, without one main one like TileCollision calling the others?

Comment: The former sounds better. Avoid type switched and things will generally be good.

Answer (score 0):

> `CharacterEntities` are the ones that have a will to do things

Read that very carefully: "ones that ***have a*** will". Now, ask yourself a question: is inheritance how we express "have a" relationships in C++?

No, it is not. Inheritance represents "is a" relationships. Storing a member variable represents "has a"; the type "has a" variable. So your "entities that have a will" types should be... `Entity`s that *have a* will.

So you need some type that represents the desire to move in a direction (how that type gets provided with said direction is more-or-less irrelevant. It could come from AI, user-interface, or whatever). And each `Entity` may *or may not* have such a thing. If it does, then your collision resolution can detect that (the pointer will be `NULL` if it's not present) and can act appropriately.

You have designed yourself in a corner because you misused a language feature. Once you design your classes correctly, you'll find that your problem works itself out.

This is the foundation of [component-based entity systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, does this mean the Entity class would contain a pointer to a class that contains all the boolean variables?

Comment: Also, to my understanding, CharacterEntites _are_ Entities, only with additional variables? Or is this wrong? Because 100% of the actions the Entites does, the Character does as well, plus its own.